# How do you programmatically configure static assets in Tomcat 8?

Tags: java, tomcat, assets, embedded-tomcat-7

I'm programmatically (no web.xml) configuring a Tomcat 8 application and I'd like to load static assets (html, images, css, etc.) from the classpath.

I've done the equivalent for Jetty using ResourceHandler:

```
ResourceHandler resourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
String webDir = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("assets").toExternalForm();
resourceHandler.setResourceBase(webDir);
```

How exactly is this done in Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

In java.lang.Class class having such a method's which load the assert pragmatically 
e.g.

```
 public URL getResource(String name)
 public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name)
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my question. I'd like to specify a path to a directory in the classpath where assets are located. Not a single asset/file.